# How can I make my web server visible to everyone?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I've installed apache2, I can access the website it has locally.
Port 80 is open, and forwarded to my webservers ip, I checked it here:

[image: screenshot]

But when I type mypublicip:80 on my web browser, it says connection refused.
I have also allowed the port 80 using ufw but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've asked a friend to test it on his phone and it worked, but why doesnt it work on mine?

Answer (score 0):

That is a security measure, Any packet from a private address will be rejected by Your Router (Modem) external interface which hold your Public IP and has 80 open.

```
  Your PC             Your Router (Modem)                     Internet 
Private IP <---+-> [Private IP -- Public IP:80] <--~ISP~--> Whatever IP's
               |                                                 ^
Another PC     |                                                 |
Private IP <---/                                                 |
                                                                 |
 Friend PC           Friend Router (Modem)                       |
Private IP <-----> [Private IP -- Public IP] <--~ISP~------------/
```

So trying to connect your PublicIP:80 as it seen from your router prospective:

- Your PC PC (PrivateIP) is rejected
- Another PC (PrivateIP) from same LAN is rejected
- Friend PC (**PublicIP**) is accepted
- Another web server (**PublicIP**) as you did the port test is accepted

The solution is to use an *external proxy* for your phone.

Comment: It should also be noted that you can modify your hosts files on each of your internal devices that points `domain.tld` to `internal.ip.of.server`. Or, set-up a local DNS server that resolves `domain.tld` to `internal.ip.of.server` and set all of your devices to use that DNS.